# Не работает @keyframes в СSS

Tags: html5, css3

Создал анимацию @keyframes, которая должна сначала переместить квадрат (сlass="one1") вверх на 200px, после чего растянуть его width до 500px и остаться в положении последнего кадра (растянутый прямоугольник шириной 500px).

```
.one1{
  margin-top: 200px;
  animation: rising 1s ease;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes rising {
  0%{
    transform: translate(0);
    }
  50%{
    transform: translateY(-200px);
    }
  100%{
    width: 500px;
  }
}
```

Но результат отличается от задуманного, вот: https://codepen.io/Nastromo/pen/MoxOva. Не могу понять почему. Помогите, пожалуйста, достичь желаемой анимации. Заранее благодарю, всех кто заинтересуется.

Comment: Не особо понятна необходимая последовательность в анимации. На данный момент она работает так, как и написано в `keyframes`

Comment: @Cheg, квадрат наверх, а там его растянуть. Написано в первом предложении.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Анимируемые значения интерполируются во всех точках, если они там не заданы. Чтобы получить желаемое поведение (сначала перемещение, а потом растяжение), надо прописать оба свойства в анимации:

```
@keyframes rising {
  0% {
    width: 200px;
    transform: translate(0);
  }
  50% {
    width: 200px;
    transform: translateY(-200px);
  }
  100% {
    width: 500px;
    transform: translateY(-200px);
  }
}
```

Comment: Благодарю, Qwertiy! Помогло.

Comment: @Nastromo, тогда прими ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него.